# How can I bundle my index.html in my webpack bundle

Tags: scalajs-bundler

I have defined a very basic [project](https://github.com/hughgearse/repro) that uses the scalajs-bundler plugin. I have defined an index.html file in my src/resources folder. Is there a way I can configure it so that this is also copied to the "target/.../scalajs-bundler/main" folder when I run the "fastOptJS::webpack" command?

Answer (score 0):

This is not the responsibility of the webpack tool. You should just define a custom sbt task that copies your HTML file.

Comment: When I added a file i18n.js to my src/main/resources folder. This is automatically added to the bundle when I run webpack. Why does it copy this file and not any others?

Comment: Currently, all .js files on the classpath can be included in the resulting bundle. See my detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56832264/561721)