# How does webpack determine which files/folders it will include in a bundle

Tags: scalajs-bundler

I have a set of files in my project's **src/main/resources** folder - such as index.html, myproject.css, i18n.js

When I run webpack only one file is automatically copied over to the bundle, namely **118n.js**. Why does this get bundled but nothing else?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, all the `.js` files on the classpath are eligible to be bundled. This is why your `i18n.js` file is included in the resulting bundle.

Note, however, that it is not planned to continue to support this behavior (relying on `.js` files on the classpath). Instead, you should include which resources are eligible to be bundled with the `jsSourceDirectories` setting key. For instance, to include all the files of the `src/main/resources` directory:

```scala
jsSourceDirectories += (Compile / resourceDirectory).value
```

Comment: Should this be added to my settings in the build.sbt? When I try this I get an error: "Cannot resolve symbol jsSourceDirectories". Using version 0.14 of scalajs-bundler

Comment: It is available from version 0.15.0 only.

Comment: @JulienRichard-Foy shouldn't it be `jsSourceDirectories in Compile`?